# AWS Lambda is returning truncated image ( binary response )

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using the following architecture

Cloudfront is in the front of the APIGateway and APIgateway has Lambda proxy as the endpoint.

When a user request for an image, request goes to the cloudfront, which in turn goes to the APIgateway and to the Lambda proxy.

LambdaProxy makes the API call to the CDN and fetch a image.

Now, APIgateway is returning the truncated image everytime. I am not sure whats wrong with the below code

```
const axios = require('axios')
// const sharp = require('sharp')
const redis = require('redis')
const aws = require("aws-sdk")

var redisClient;
exports.handler =  async (event,context,callback) => {

    const result = await axios({
        url: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/18/19/31/laptop-5582775_1280.jpg", 
        method:"GET" ,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        // headers : lambdaEvent.headers
        })            
            
        const buffer = Buffer.from(result.data)
                const base64Buffer = buffer.toString("base64")
                console.log( "Base64 encoded image is" + base64Buffer)
                
                const imageResponse = {
                    "statusCode" : result.status,
                    "headers":{"Content-type":"image/jpeg"},
                    "body":base64Buffer,
                    "isBase64Encoded": true
                }

            return imageResponse
}
```

I have validated `result.data` is the correct image by creating a file in S3.

I have validated `baseg64Buffer` is the correct encoded string by online translating the base64Buffer to image. It shows me the expected image.

However, APIGateway response is always truncated to the browser.

[image]

Can any one help what wrong with this code.

Comment: Does the response size exceed the limits? APIGateway limit is 10mb, Lambda is 6mb...

Comment: I do not think so, for the same images it was working earlier.